# Why only one of two function is fired on `onClick` event?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an `onClick` event on a button where I call 2 JS function :

```php
<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase shadow-lg" type="button" style="margin-right: 50px;" onclick="JaxonCreate.createProjet(document.getElementById('inNom').value,document.getElementById('inDate').value,document.getElementById('inFm').value,document.getElementById('inFree').value,document.getElementById('inIneo').value,document.getElementById('inDep').value,document.getElementById('inType').value,document.getElementById('inOpe').value,document.getElementById('inNra').value,document.getElementById('inCdd').value,document.getElementById('inCreer').value);window.close();">envoyer</button>
```

The first function I call is `JaxonCreate.createProjet()` which calls a PHP function :

```php
Class Create
{
    public function createProjet(string $projetNom, string $projetLance, string $projetFm, string $projetFree, string $projetIneo, string $projetDep, string $projetType, string $projetOpe, string $nraNom, string $nraEtat, string $nraCreer){

        $projetNom = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetNom)."'";
        $projetLance = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetLance)."'";
        $projetFm = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetFm)."'";
        $projetFree = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetFree)."'";
        $projetIneo = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetIneo)."'";
        $projetDep = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetDep)."'";
        $projetType = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetType)."'";
        $projetOpe = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $projetOpe)."'";
        $nraNom = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $nraNom)."'";
        $nraEtat = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $nraEtat)."'";
        $nraCreer = " '".str_replace("'", "''", $nraCreer)."'";

        $requete1 = "insert into projet(projet_nom, projet_date_lancement, projet_date_fm, projet_cdp_free, projet_cdp_ineo, projet_departement, projet_type_bts, projet_operateur_bts) values ($projetNom,$projetLance, $projetFm, $projetFree, $projetIneo, $projetDep, $projetType, $projetOpe)";
        $requete2 = "update nra set nra_nom = $nraNom, nra_etat_cdd = $nraEtat, nra_n1_creer = $nraCreer where nra_id = (select lastval());";

        Db::query($requete1);
        Db::query($requete2);

    }
}
```

When I call the 2 functions at `onClick` event I do like this :

```php
onClick="function1(); function2();">
```

I've used this way to call 2 functions many times on other pages, but here it only fires `window.close()` not `JaxonCreate.createProjet()`. And when there is only one function at the time they both works.

I don't understand why ?

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Once you close a browser window, that's it.  Forget any other code you have sent..  Maybe do createProject then close instead.

Comment: I agree with @Keith. Try writing `echo '<script>window.close();</script>';` after `Db::query($requete2);` and call only JaxonCreate.createProjet() .This will print the javascript code on the page and must close the window.

Comment: @Dharman Yes true, I want first to focus to make something working ,then I will implement prepared statements

Comment: @Keith I'm going to try that .

Comment: What are you doing with the quotes and `str_replace`? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Dharman I'm testing if I can do special characters escaping (not sure how you say in english)

Comment: @Dejvid I tried what you suggested and it doesn't work. It does the same than before. If think, as suggested Jonny in below answer, either it is because I call other functions in my first function or my first function (which is an an UPDATE SQL query) is longuer than the second one.

Comment: What do you want to escape from? Why do you want to escape anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know PHP, but looking at the markup and JS I believe the problem might be one of two things.

Firstly, have you tried calling a function that will subsequently call two functions like this:

```
onClick="initMyFunctions()"

function initMyFunctions() {
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
}
```

Secondly, could your first function be taking longer to execute than your second function?

**JS Callback**

Have you tried implementing a javascript callback to ensure that the second function only runs once the first function has finished?
Callbacks: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Initially you could log to the console to see what is executing in what order and when, in order to get a better idea of what is happening in terms of execution order and timings.

Comment: As I'm learning by doing, I wasn't aware of callback. I'm going to have a look at you say. It might be as you said, because my first function is longuer than the second one to execute.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the use of `hide()` in a callback.
Does it mean I have to write someting like :
`onClick="function().hide("slow", function());"` 
?

Comment: @LyessD - the hide() in that example is just using hide() as an example to demonstrate the order of things. Sorry, possibly a bit confusing if you're just learning. Essentially in the first example they are using hide() to animate the <p> to be invisible, and once that has completed, and only once that has completed, they call another function to display an alert message - this function is the callback.
I have edited my answer to link to a more general resource about what a callback is and how it works.

Comment: The aim of a callback is to invoke a function once an operation has completed. In essence, this is actually what @Dejvid is suggesting in his answer above, - if you put 
    echo '<script>window.close();</script>'; after Db::query($requete2); 
that should call your close() function only once the PHP code has run and completed.